# GoogleMap doesn't display the current location while using onMapReady

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

OnMapReady gets called before ReadCsvFile() is executed,which fetches the latlng points from the a CSV file.Hence when map is displayed, it doesn't show the current Location.How can i make sure onMapReday is called only after latLng points are fetched from the file? How to prevent getting a null pointer exception at 
"googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17));"

```
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    ReadCsvFile(this);
    for (LocationHelperBean locationHelperBean : parameterList) {
        latLng=new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(locationHelperBean.getLatitude())), Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(locationHelperBean.getLongitude())));
          arrayPoints.add(latLng);
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().snippet("latitude:" + latitude + "longitude:" + longitude + "bearing:" + bearing + "accuracy:" + accuracy + "altitude" + altitude + "speed" + speed).position(latLng).draggable(true));

    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().add(latLng).width(6).color(Color.RED).geodesic(true);

    polylineOptions.addAll(arrayPoints);

    map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: ReadCsvFile fetches the latLng points from the file.But, since onMapReady gets executed before ReadCsvFile, latLng is null when map is displayed.How can i prevent this? How can i make sure onMapReady is called only after latLng has a value?

Answer (score 0):

If you use MapView you could just call `onCreate(null)` after you have obtained everything from `readCsvFile()` to set up the map. Otherwise just get the GoogleMap when it's ready and call `setupMap()` when `readCsvFile()` finished like so:

```
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    this.map = map;
    setupMap();
}

private void setupMap() {
    if (map != null && latLng != null) {
        // Do something with map (e.g. add markers,...)
    }
}
```